# Emigration to UK vs English language skills

Tags: php

I have completed technical secondary school this year (I'm 20) in Poland. I work as freelance web developer for 4 years (PHP very good, MySQL strong basics, HTML excellent, CSS excellent, JS/AJAX/jQuery basics).

So I don't have academic education yet. I'm planning to start studying computer science this year, but I hit on an idea to emigrate to London (or Dublin/Amsterdam/Madrit/Barcelona maybe?) for one year, then come back to Poland and start studying here.
The goal is to improve my English skills, enhance some work exp, get to know how living abroad looks like, meet new people/cultures.

My main fear and problem is English language level. Usually I don't have problems with reading and writing, but speaking and listening is not my strong competence. My English isn't fluent and is not very good currently (I think it's communicative, but in small/middle level).

My experience: > 30 websites (with CMS, etc) [within this few bigger portals], few computer programs. I worked in a advertising agency (half year in 2010); now I cooperate for 1,5 year with another ad agency which gives me websites to create. I will try to get references from most of my clients and from my bosses of that advertising agencies.

What do you think, do I have some chances to get some job as junior web developer / PHP programmer?

Thank you in advance for your help and advices.
Regards!!!
PS. Why stackexchange throws out "Hi" or "Hello" from the beginning of the post? :O

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. This post is off topic (this site is not about career decisions). Also, see [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) about using why hellos are removed.

Answer (score 1):

Well your English writing is pretty much understandable. So I don't see why moving abroad will be that much of a problem. Even if you have more trouble speaking it and understanding it it's not something that should keep you from traveling. As long as you have other skills to fall back on for a job I think that's good. If you speak Polish fluently. Why not look up which of your possible destinations have large Polish communities so you can at least communicate with some locals if needed or for work if you don't get a job as a junior developer. Good luck where ever you go

Comment: Hi Anagio, thanks for your reply! I know I can get a whatsoever job (and I will do it if I can't get a job in IT), but I want to rank my chances of get a job as a web developer ;-) and I think IT companies require fluent English, is it true?
About Polish communities - I would shy off that because I want to speak English (to learn the language), not Polish ;-) Regards

Comment: I don't know what web companies require i'm sure it's different for each company regardless of where they are located. Craigslist usually has a good amount of IT jobs in most countries. Applying before you go would be good with a portfolio and client feedback

Comment: You're welcome, if you feel this answered your question feel free to tick it as the answer, have a nice trip

Comment: I would like to vote your post up, but unfortunately I don't have 15 reputation points. About tick as the answer - I would like to read other people opinion as well ;-)